# Unable to view "Maintenance Plan" folder under Maintenance in SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, maintenance

SQL Server version is as follows :

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2  (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

In SQL Server Management Studio, under the Management node, I am unable to view the "Maintenence Folder" node.  I am logged in as `sa`, and the account does have the `sysadmin` server role.

How do I get access to the "Maintenance Folder"?

Comment: Can you see Maintenance Plans in `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders;`?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Hi Shawn, I am not getting any error. Unbale to find Maintenance folder

Comment: Hi Michal, Please see the following result of query : 08AA12D5-8F98-4DAB-A4FC-980B150A5DC8                       00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000                Maintenance Plans

Comment: Which version of Management Studio are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.50.1600.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      3.85.1117
Microsoft MSXML      2.6 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      8.0.6001.18702
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.3053
Operating System      5.1.2600

Comment: ANY ONE Please help me................

Comment: Please any one help to solve this